# ASP.net MVC Action link produces links with params after?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm having what I think is a routing issue.  Here's my route:

```
        context.MapRoute
        (
            "MonthYearRoute",                                                                   // Route name
            "TimeEntry/{action}/{month}/{year}",                                                // URL
            new { controller = "TimeEntry", action = "Month" }, new { month = new IntConstraint(), year = new IntConstraint() } // Defaults
        );
```

Here's my ActionLink code:

```
        @Html.ActionLink(
            "By Week", 
            "Month", 
            "TimeEntry", 
            new { month = Model.MonthNumber, year = Model.YearNumber }, 
            new { @class = GetClassName("TimeEntry", "Month") }
        )
```

This is supposed to create a url like this:

"/TimeEntry/Month/12/2011"

But it's producing this:

"TimeEntry/Month?month=12&year=2011"

How do I format the URL to look like "/TimeEntry/Month/12/2011"?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: a copy of your routing table definitions would help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably due to the order of route definitions in your Global.asax. Make sure that your specific routes are *before* generic routes.